# how to drop oracle 12c instance on linux

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have created an Oracle 12c container db instance.  I need to drop the  instance. What's the most effective way to drop instance?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> startup force mount exclusive restrict
SQL> drop database;
```